# Coffeescript Parse error unexpected '.'

Tags: javascript, parsing, compilation, coffeescript, bots

I am trying to compile .coffee files into .js files but i keep getting this error i have no idea whats wrong but thanks in advance

```
C:\Documents and Settings\USER\Desktop\Bots\b>coffee
coffee> --bare -l --compile *.coffee
Error: In repl, Parse error on line 1: Unexpected '.'
at Object.parseError (C:\Documents and Settings\USER\Application Data\npm\no
de_modules\coffee-script\lib\coffee-script\parser.js:470:11)
at Object.parse (C:\Documents and Settings\USER\Application Data\npm\node_mo
dules\coffee-script\lib\coffee-script\parser.js:546:22)
at C:\Documents and Settings\USER\Application Data\npm\node_modules\coffee-s
cript\lib\coffee-script\coffee-script.js:40:22
at Object.eval (C:\Documents and Settings\USER\Application Data\npm\node_mod
ules\coffee-script\lib\coffee-script\coffee-script.js:123:10)
at Interface. (C:\Documents and Settings\USER\Application Data\np
m\node_modules\coffee-script\lib\coffee-script\repl.js:51:34)
at Interface.emit (events.js:67:17)
at Interface._onLine (readline.js:162:10)
at Interface._line (readline.js:426:8)
at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:603:14)
at ReadStream. (readline.js:82:12)
coffee>
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know CoffeScript in particular, but it seems to me that you're trying to give the command line options in the interactive shell. Try to give the options as a parameter:

> C:\Documents and Settings\USER\Desktop\Bots\b>coffee --bare -l --compile *.coffee

Comment: Exactly right. When you run `coffee` by itself, you enter the REPL, where you're expected to enter CoffeeScript expressions, not shell commands. Press Ctrl+C to exit the REPL.